# Prove for each prime number $p$ there are infinite numbers like $ 2^n - n $ such that $ p | 2^n -n $. ($ n \in \mathbb {N} $)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

First I separated $p=2$ because it's the only even prime. Since $2$ only can divide a number if and only if it's even, and $2^n$ is even, so $n$ must be even, too. Thus, $2$ divides $2^n -n$ for every $n$ that is even.
For the rest of the prime numbers, I thought of using mathematical induction, but I couldn't find the right way of using it here.
I was wondering if someone could help me prove this.

Comment: Here's a hint, $2^n \mod p$ and $n \mod p$ are periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: What about $n$ of the form $n=(kp-1)(p-1)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't get it completely. by this you want me to make $(2^{p-1})^{kp-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ ?  I mean you want to show the periodic pattern but I don't understand how am I supposed to use it.

Comment: Note that for $n=(p-1)(kp-1)$ for any positive integer $k$, that both $n \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $2^n = (2^{p-1})^{kp-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Thus, $2^n-n \equiv 1-1 \pmod p$ for each such $n$. So $2^n-n \equiv 0 \pmod p$ thus $p|(2^n-n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try using Fermat's little theorem. Can you make $2^n\equiv n\equiv 1\pmod p$?

Comment: I don't know how to prove $n \equiv 1 \mod p$. can you please help me with it?

Comment: @ArithEgo $2^n\equiv 1$ depends on $n\pmod p$, whereas $n\equiv 1$ depends on $n\pmod {p-1}$, and $p,p-1$ are coprime.